# Possible ajax way to hide Email address on a website from spam bots?

Tags: jquery, ajax, email, spam-prevention

Would it theoretically block email crawler by showing the email address only after a click on a non-link element (for example div or span) and load the email address per jQuery + ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically Yes it will. Now a days some sites display email address even in dynamically generated images to prevent being crawled.